# Supressing debug logs when inheriting from core CodeIgniter classes?

Tags: codeigniter

Whenever a core class is initialized, a line is written to the debug log. For example, if CI_Model is instantiated, you'll see a "Model Class Initialized". I want to suppress this.

When I inherit from CI_Model, I call the parent constructor, which outputs that line. In the inherited class, I am also outputting a similar line. For example "CustomModel Class Initialized".

Unfortunately, this gives me two lines in the logs, one that is helpful, and one that is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would just be to go into *system/core/Model.php* and comment the line out.

Another approach would be to log the message from your CustomModel class with a message level other than *debug*.  Then, update the log threshold in *application/config/config.php* to disable logging of debug messages.  The downside to this approach is that you won't log all of the other system messages.

If all you're really trying to accomplish is to remove that one log message, I don't see any harm in just going into the core class and removing the line.